# How best to store time ranges like Tuesday 10-11am?

Tags: mysql

It's not a one-of, not only one particular Tuesday, so I won't use time stamps.

I mean something like "every Tuesday from 10am to 11am". What's the best way to store this to make it easy to check from my (Delphi) application if the current time is between those permitted times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the time range would simply be an attribute of whichever primary object you are working with, as such you could add a separate table to store the time range data, something like:

```
object_time_range
    id
    object_id
    day
    hour_start
    hour_end
    frequency_id
```

-- Update --

In hindsight I would probably abstract hour from the column names in favor of time, just in case you need to consider alternative time frames. And day should be day_id, even though its a static list, I always like going with ints in this situation.

```
object_time_range
    id
    object_id
    day_id
    time_start
    time_end
    frequency_id
```

Comment: This help? If not, add some more info to OP so I can get a better idea.

Comment: @Mawg: Good to hear, wasn't exactly sure what you were going for. I made an update with some notes.

Answer (score -1):

Store the variable as datetime or timestamp,

you can use mysql date functions such as

```
date_format and date_add
```

to get the rows which fall within required dates and time

if you store it as text it would be very difficult.

E.g To get rows for the past one day

```
select * from tableName 
where dateField  > date_add(now(),interval -1 day) and
dateField < now()  

rows for the past one Week

select * from tableName 
where dateField  > date_add(now(),interval -1 week) and
dateField < now()
```

Check date_add funciton